# VS 2015 & VS 2017 failed to detect Physical Device

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Using VS 2015 i Debug the App on Physical Device .

But After install VS 2017 preview 15.3 preview 3 both VS 2015 And 2017 failed to detect the Physical device and only the emulators are added,

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2F1z.jpg)

I want to using the physical device especially with VS 2015.

Comment: does your PC detect the device?  Do you have the correct USB drivers installed?  Do you have developer mode and USB debugging enabled on the device?

Comment: yes every thing was installed and detected just before installing vs 2017

Comment: Ensure that your device is listed in `adb devices`. If it is not, then VS will not pick it up.

Comment: This could be an issue with vs2017 compatibility with vs2015. Try to uninstall 2017 and reinstall 2015

Comment: @IvanBukashkin working with both vs2015 and vs2017 generates a bug not sure but this cause a crash for the whole OS and i had to install a new OS for my machine

Answer (score 0):

For me in spite of using Samsung device VS detect the device after download the USB Driver
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/#Download_the_USB_Drivers